# Failed to create list item for external list using REST API POST

Tags: external-content-type, external-list, odata, business-data-catalog

I've AN OData API, which I'm consuming in SharePoint via BCS and External List.

I already have the Get and Update functionality working using REST API to external list.

But when I try to add an item in the list, I'm getting the following error:

In the ULS Log the detail of the Internal Server Error(500), was

> Internal Server Error. --->
>   Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.CannotConnectException

Here is the error using Fiddler:

> message=Failed to create a list item for this external list based on
>   the Entity (External Content Type) 'xxx-table-name-xxx' in
>   EntityNamespace 'XXX'. Details: The remote server returned an error:
>   (500) Internal Server Error.
>
> stacktrace=   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListDataSource.InsertItem(SPListItem
>   itemToInsert, IDictionary dictValues)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean
>   bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean
>   bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin,
>   Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object&
>   objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem,
>   Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration,
>   Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean
>   bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename, Boolean
>   bPreserveItemUIVersion)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemEntityCollection.Create()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemEntityCollectionServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
>   target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethodWithRequestODataEntry(Object
>   target, ServerStub serverStub, MethodInformation methodInfo,
>   RequestODataObject entry)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethodWithRequestODataEntry(Object
>   target, ServerStub serverStub, String methodName)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.TryAddEntity(Object
>   entity, ServerStub serverStub, Object& newEntity)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream
>   inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)

Answer (score 1):

I have a code which may be useful for you.
Try this-

```
    function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItemTitle) {

var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    "Title": newItemTitle
}

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {  
        alert("New Item has been created successfully. ")
         },  
    error: function(data)  {   
        alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again.")
       }  
    });
```

};

```
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
```

}